# How to add multiple event to android marshmallow Calendar?

Tags: android

Events are adding to calendar properly till api 22.

I have also implemented run- time permissions for Marshmallow , Calender permission is allowed in Phone setting for my application is clearly visible.

But still nothing is updating on phone calendar and also app giving no error or warning.

Below is my method to add event programatically on phone calendar.

```
    private void addEventToCalender(Activity ourActivity, String title, String desc, String place, int status, long startDate, long endDte, boolean needReminder, boolean needMailService) {
        try {
            String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
            ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
            eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1); // id, We need to choose from         // our mobile for primary its 1
            eventValues.put("title", "My Title");
            eventValues.put("description","My Description" );
            eventValues.put("eventLocation", "Noida,UP ";

            eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);
            eventValues.put("dtend", endDte);
            eventValues.put("allDay", 1); // 1 for whole day 
            //eventValues.put("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");

            // values.put("allDay", 1); //If it is bithday alarm or such
            // kind (which should remind me for whole day) 0 for false, 1
            // for true
            eventValues.put("eventStatus", 1); // This information is
            // sufficient for most
            // entries tentative (0),
            // confirmed (1) or canceled
            // (2):
            eventValues.put("eventTimezone", "UTC/GMT " + Constants.tzone);
            eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
            Uri eventUri = this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
            long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
            Log.i("eventID", eventID + "");
            showSnackBar("Event added to calender successfuly.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("error", "Error in adding event on calendar" + ex.getMessage());
            showSnackBar("Ünable to add event to calender!");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Above code have no problem, the problem was with the google calendar app latest update, so after uninstalling latest update i am now able to add multiple events on marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to use inside Fragment .

at first use :

```
super.requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

Inside fragment, you need to call:

```
FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(permissionsList, RequestCode)
```

Note:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity, permissionsList, RequestCode);
```

add this library for FragmentCompat class in app.gradle.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:version_of_library'
```